# ASP.NET Request timeouts middleware, how to cancel any endpoint action after timeout expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, task

I have asp.net web api with controller's methods witch not implement cancellation token, for example:

```
[HttpGet(nameof(Get))]
public async Task<UserDto> Get([FromQuery] Guid userId) => await _userService.GetAsync(userId);
```

and like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0
I added RequestTimeoutsOptions to ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
        services.AddRequestTimeouts(options =>
            options.DefaultPolicy =
                new RequestTimeoutPolicy
                {
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_requestTimeoutMs)
                });
...
}
```

and RequestTimeout midleware in Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
    app.UseSession()
        .UseEndpoints(routes => { routes.MapControllers(); });
    app.UseRequestTimeouts();
...
}
```

But after timeout expired nothing happens, only context.RequestAborted token become cancelled.

How I can cancel any endpoint method task without adding cancelationToken parameter to all of them?

Comment: Timeouts are communicated by the cancellation token. How else would they possibly work? To respond to the timeout, observe the cancellation token.

Comment: I mean, can I wrap method calling to anoter task in midleware or some another way to cover all endpoints, like app.Use(async (context, next) => { await Task.Run(async () => await next.Invoke(), context.RequestAborted); });

Comment: No, that won't work. The cancellation token passed to `Task.Run` cancels the *scheduling* of the delegate, not the delegate itself.